# How can change the focus on the JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have built simple java swing application. Now in my JPanel, I have some JTextField and one JTable.
So I have implemented a my custom focus, if the focus is on the JTextFiled1 and I press ENTER, the focus automatically change on the JTextFiled2 etc.
The last element that receive the focus is JTable. Now I don't want that the focus is on the first column but on the fourth column, so I have this code:

```
textDescrizione.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0), "myTabAction");
textDescrizione.getActionMap().put("myTabAction", new AbstractAction("myTabAction") {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tableConti.requestFocus();
        tableConti.editCellAt(0,4);
    }
});
```

this code works, I have the focus on my fouth cell, but if I try to press right button on my keyboard, the focus is not of the five column but on the first column.
How can I change this?

Another question is, I have implemented a keyListener on my JTable, so if I try to press F5 when JTable have the focus, I call a method. Also thi works but the focus remains on the cell.

This is the code:

keyListener

```
public class MyKeyListenerSalvataggio extends KeyAdapter{
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F5){
            salva();
        }

    }
};

tableConti.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListenerSalvataggio());
```

After that I have press F5, the method salva() finish this is the situation:

[image]

As you can see, I'm not able to clean the value of the table, and delete the focus on the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell the table to stop editing the cell. See [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/) for a couple of approaches:

1. In the ActionListener you stop the cell editing, or
2. You can set a property of the table to stop editing when it loses focus

Comment: for my second question, your answer is good. Thanks you, but for the first question?

Comment: @bircastri By the way don't use a KeyListener for the F5 key. Swing was designed to be used with KeyBindings. I don't understand your "first question". The right arrow key will only move the caret in the text field, it will not change focus to another component.

Comment: My First question is, when I click enter and I'm on the last JTextField, my jtable, receive the focus, I have write my code to do this. I have the focus on the fourth column of the first row of my JTable. Now if I want to move the focus on the third column or fifth column I use my right click button of my keyboard or left button, right? So the focus not move on the third or fifth, but at the first column

Comment: @bircastri, try using the `changeSelection(...)` method of JTable in your custom Action before using the editCellAt(...) method.